# What does "sensitive for" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> *The BLOSUM matrices are calculated matrices, most sensitive for local alignment of related sequences, ideal when trying to identify an unknown nucleotide sequence.*

What is the meaning of "sensitive for" here?

Comment: I don't think we have enough information to say definitively.  More context is required.

Comment: Is your example a complete sentence? It looks like you left some words off the beginning.

Comment: It's a scientific description about DNA sequences.

Comment: In Bioinformatics, one possible definition of *sensitivity* is "the probability to match an alignment generated from a particular probabilistic alignment model." Ref. http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-87361-7_27#page-2

Comment: It most likely means that these matrices are most sensitive **when used for** certain purposes. But I still don't think enough context has been provided to know this is the answer on purely grammatical grounds.

Comment: I think this is more of a technical question than an English language question. Maybe it should be migrated to the Biology SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a scientific bit of jargon.

Here we have an algorithm used in DNA sequencing that is used to search for sequences that at similar to other sequences. Searching instruments, whether physical or mathematical, can be more or less sensitive.  A sensitive thermometer detects smaller changes; a sensitive voltmeter measures smaller differences in voltage than a less sensitive meter. This calculational method is 'more sensitive' when used to look for some things than for others. It's a typical sentence structure when discussing this sort of thing.